# Impresión de una cadena de caracteres al revés en C

Tags: c, punteros, array

Mi duda es principalmente con la función `reverse`, el problema es que no entiendo en qué momento, o cómo es que realiza la inversión de la cadena de caracteres.

Es decir, cada una de las sentencias por separado las entiendo, más no la función completa. Espero puedan explicarme.

```
include <stdio.h>
include <conio.h>
include <stdlib.h>
include <string.h>
include <ctype.h>
include <math.h>
include <time.h>

void reverse(const char *const sPtr);

int main()
{
    char sentence[80];

    printf("Enter a line of text:\n");

    fgets(sentence, 80, stdin);

    printf("\nThe line printed backwad is:\n");
    reverse(sentence);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void reverse(const char *const sPtr)
{
    if(sPtr[0] == '\0')
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        reverse(&sPtr[1]);
        putchar(sPtr[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void reverse(const char *const sPtr)
{
    if(sPtr[0] == '\0')
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        reverse(&sPtr[1]);
        putchar(sPtr[0]);
    }
}
```

Si el puntero pasado como argumento es `== 0` (fin de la cadena), termina.

En otro caso, llama recursivamente a la propia función `reverse( )` y, **al retornar de esta llamada recursiva**, muestra el caracter al que apunta `sPtr`.

Esas llamadas recursivas a la propia función `reverse( )` son una forma *enrevesada* de hacer eso, imprimir la cadena al revés. Cada nueva llamada se hace pasando como argumento **la dirección siguiente a la actual** a la que apunta `sPtr`:

```
1ª llamada -> sPtr = cadena[0];
2ª llamada -> sPtr = cadena[1];
3ª llamada -> sPtr = cadena[2];
```

Cuando llegas al final de la cadena, el `if == '\0'` **corta** la recursividad. Entonces, es cuando se realiza la llamada a `putchar( )`, que imprime el caracter. La primera vez que se llama a `putchar( )`, es porque estamos en `cadena[strlen(cadena)-1]`.

Ahora, en cada retorno, imprimimos *el caracter anterior al último que imprimimos*.

**EDITO**

A ver si así queda más claro:

En cada *invocación* a `reverse( )`, vamos avanzando por la cadena.
En cada *retorno*, imprimimos un caracter.

Puesto que **nunca retornamos** antes de llegar al final, el primero retorno se hace cuando estamos justo al final, y eso es lo primero que se imprime, el último caracter.

El segundo retorno, imprime el penúltimo caracter.

Y así, en cada retorno imprimimos el caracter anterior, hasta que llegamos al último retorno, que imprime el primer caracter.

Algo enrevesado, pero simple.

Answer (score 2):

Imagina que `sentence[0]` está en la dirección de memoria 0x10. Y que contiene `"JML"`.

`&variable[0]` es la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del array; con lo que `&sentence[0]` es `0x10`.
Y `&sentence[1]` es `0x11`

```
Memoria :
0x10 0x11 0x12 0x13
 J     L    M   \0

reverse( sentence )  -> sentence es la dirección 0x10
  |- recibimos sPtr=0x10
  |- en 0x10 no hay '\0' luego llama a :
  |- reverse( &sPtr[1] ) -> &sPtr[1] es la dirección 0x11
  |   |- recibimos sPtr=0x11; este sPtr es uno distinto del de la función que nos ha llamado 
  |   |- en 0x11 no hay '\0' luego llama a :
  |   |- reverse( &sPtr[1] ) -> &sPtr[1] es la dirección 0x12
  |   |    |- recibimos sPtr=0x12
  |   |    |- en 0x12 no hay '\0' luego llama a :
  |   |    |- reverse( &sPtr[1] ) -> &sPtr[1] es la dirección 0x13
  |   |    |     |- recibimos sPtr=13
  |   |    |     \- en 0x13 sí hay '\0' luego volvemos
  |   |    \- imprimir carácter en sPtr[0]; recordar que sPtr=0x12; el caracter es 'M'
  |   \- imprimir carácter en sPtr[0]; recordar que sPtr=0x11; el caracter es 'L' 
  \-imprimir carácter en sPtr[0]; recordar que sPtr=0x10; el caracter es 'J'
```

Como ves la función se llama a sí misma de forma recursiva pasándose cada vez una dirección mayor de la cadena de caracteres hasta que llega al terminador `'\0'`. Y luego va volviendo a la llamada anterior e imprimiendo los caracteres.