# ¿Porque se ejecuta una instruccion a pesar de ser saltada o finalizada anteriormente?

Tags: c++, archivo

Estoy creando una pequeña interfaz para un proyecto que la usa en la que se comprueba la existencia de archivos y su contenido, para ello tengo este codigo el cual funciona perfectamente para ese uso.

```
 void abrirFichero(){
    cout << "Eleccion de ficheros de usos y usuarios. Opciones disponibles:\n"; 
    cout << "   16: octubre 2016 a marzo 2017" << endl;
    cout << "   17: marzo 2017 a agosto 2017" << endl;              

    cout << "Introduzca una opcion: ";
    string opcion;
    getline (std::cin,opcion);                                      

    const char *numero = opcion.c_str();                            
    char direccion[35] = "..\\..\\Datos\\Bici\\usos-";
    strcat (direccion, numero);                                     
    const char direccion2[5] = ".csv";
    strcat (direccion, direccion2);                                  

    int utilizaciones = 0;
    int usuarios = 0;
    ifstream f;                                                     
    f.open (direccion);                                             
    if(f.is_open()){                                                
        while (!f.eof()){
            if(f.get()=='\n'){
                utilizaciones++;                                    
            }
        }
    }
    else{ 
        cout << "\nNo se ha podido abrir el fichero" << direccion << "\n\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
        abrirFichero();
    }
    f.close();                                                      

    char direccion1[35] = "..\\..\\Datos\\Bici\\usuarios-";
    strcat (direccion1, numero);
    strcat (direccion1, direccion2);


    f.open (direccion1);                                            
    if(f.is_open()){
        while (!f.eof()){
            if(f.get()=='\n'){
                usuarios++;
            }
        }
        cout << "\nEl fichero "<< direccion <<" existe y contiene " << utilizaciones << " utilizaciones. ";     
        cout << "\nEl fichero "<< direccion1 <<" existe y contiene " << usuarios << " usuarios. ";
    }
    else{ 
        cout << "\nNo se ha podido abrir el fichero" << direccion1 << "\n\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
        abrirFichero();
    }
}
```

El problema es si se le introduce un valor que no existe y luego uno que si existe, entonces a pesar de que muestra correctamente lo pedido la ultima instruccion:

```
    else{ 
    cout << "\nNo se ha podido abrir el fichero" << direccion1 << "\n\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    abrirFichero();
}
```

Se ejecuta con el valor de el archivo pedido anteriormente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a salir de la ejecución con un return tras la representación por pantalla de los valores pero aun así esa instrucción se ejecuta y reinicia el programa. ¿Alguien tiene idea de porque pasa?

Comment: no se pero yo probaria a poner un break; cuando termine de salir lo de los usuarios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Muy sencillo. Miremos tu código, según el *pantallazo* que has puesto:

1. Introduces una opción incorrecta.
2. El primer `open( )` falla.
3. Se entra al primer `else`, que **vuelve a llamar a `abrirFichero( )` SIN terminar la ejecución actual**.
4. En esta ocasión, **introducimos una opción correcta**.
5. Los `open( )` son correctos.
6. Al terminar esta ejecución (ahora si es correcta), la ejecución **continua en el punto 3**.

por lo que seguirás intentando abrir un archivo que no existe; en tu ejemplo, sería

> ..\..\Datos\Bici\usuarios-18.csv

Y, efectivamente, colocar un `return` es inutil ... simplemente, vuelves igualmente al punto 3, por lo que no sirve para tu problema.

Me resulta *curioso* como lo has implementado, mediante recursividad en caso de error. Como solución simple y rápida, podrías envolver todo en un `while( true )`, haciendo `continue` dentro de los `else`:

```
while( true ) {
  ...

  if( f.is_open( ) ) {
  ...
  } else {
    cout << "\nNo se ha podido abrir el fichero" ...
    continue;
  }

  ...
}
```

<sub>**Nota**: Esta pregunta: [Impresión de una cadena de caracteres al revés en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/43386/19610) **ilustra** bastante bien el concepto de llamadas recursivas y como la ejecución continua donde se quedó.</sub>